# Angular: Send element from HTML

Tags: html, angular, dom, element

Is there a way to send through HTML the element as an attribute? For example:

In HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
         <my-component [ngClass]="{'whatever': checkElement(my-component)}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

In ts file:

```
checkElement(el): boolean {
     // dummy code
     const size = el.getBoundingClientRect();
     return size.bottom > 100;
}
```

I know there are several ways to get that element, but this will be used in a huge loop and I would like to prevent searching the element in the DOM (if possible).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you a template reference variable to refer to `my-component` like so:

```
<my-component [ngClass]="{'whatever': checkElement(myComponentVariableName)}" #myComponentVariableName>
```

and pass that as an argument to the method `checkElement()`. Note that here the type of `myComponentVariableName` will be `HTMLInputElement`.

Another way to access that from the `.ts` file would be to use `@ViewChild()` like so:

```
@ViewChild('myComponentVariableName') myComponentVariable: ElementRef;`.
```

Then you can use `this.myComponentVariable` anywhere inside the component.

If you are worried about having multiple `my-component`s as it is inside an `*ngFor`, you can convert the `@ViewChild` statement to make it a list like so:

```
@ViewChildren(my-component) myComponentList: QueryList<my-component>;
```

Also, track the `*ngFor` by index, and send the index along with the template reference variable like so:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;">
  <my-component [ngClass]="{'whatever': checkElement(myComponentVariableName, i)}" #myComponentVariableName>
</li>
```

Inside the `checkElement()` method, access the particular `my-component` like `myComponentList[i]`.

Comment: This is what I really wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, very easy :

```js
export class ParentComponent {
  this = this;
}
```

```html
<my-element [parentElement]="this">
```

now in your second component

```
 @Input('parentElement') parentElement: ParentComponent;
```